# Asp.Net MVC com duas views e uma URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Fiz um site que deve funcionar com a seguinte configuração.

NavBar no topo, isso está ok.

Abaixo dela eu tenho uma div container, ela é dividida em duas partes, a parte da esquerda é uma lista de, pode se chamar de tags, do lado esquerdo que é onde o site vai mesmo acontecer é a parte de formulários e tal.

Então vamos lá. Esse é o meu _Layout.cshtml:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      @Html.Partial("tags")
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      @RenderBody()
      <footer>
        ...
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Quando eu executo a URL:

```
localhost:8080/aplicacao/produtos
```

O `@RenderBody()` mostra a view `Index.cshtml` de produto onde ele lista os produtos, ela recebe o model que nada mais é que um resultado do EF.

Independente do que o `@RenderBody()` apresente o `@Html.Partial("tags")` tem que aparecer do lado, só que o conteúdo dele está sempre mudando, e importante dizer, ele não muda baseado na view do `RenderBody()` não.

Então vamos imaginar que agora eu mude para endereços, depois carros, etc... As tags devem continuar aparecendo.

Eu fiz tudo isso por JavaScript, na view de tags eu tenho um javascrip que chega uma outra URL (de tags), e carrega a pagina com o resultado.

Eu não gostei dessa solução, mas não sei como eu faria de outra forma.

Alguém tem uma solução melhor?

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo de como você está carregando as tags via javascript, não vejo por que mudar. Mas, existe uma outra forma de fazer. Seria utilizando `@Html.Action("action", "controller")` no lugar de `@Html.Partial("tags")`

Neste caso a action deve retornar uma PartialView. Ex.

Controller

```
public class TagController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly] //Caso você queira impedir que a action seja acessível via url.
    public ActionResult Listar()
    {
         var tags = MetodoParaCarregarAsTags();
         return PartialView(tags);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      @Html.Action("Listar", "Tag")
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      @RenderBody()
      <footer>
        ...
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```